# How can I setting up logrotation with ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have this in my playbook:

```
---
- name: Set Up syslog-ng Server
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Log Rotation for log
      logrotate: name=man_vc.log path="/var/log/man_vc.log"
        args:
          options:
            - daily
            - size 25M
            - rotate 8
            - missingok
            - compress
            - delaycompress
            - copytruncate
```

And when I run it I get this error:

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.


The error appears to have been in '/apps/cman/scripts/ansible/playbooks/syslog-ng_server.yaml': line 11, column 13, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

      logrotate: name=man_vc.log path="/var/log/man_vc.log"
        args:
            ^ here

exception type: <class 'yaml.scanner.ScannerError'>
exception: mapping values are not allowed in this context
  in "<unicode string>", line 11, column 13
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try "options" instead of "args"? See below from https://github.com/nickhammond/ansible-logrotate.

```
logrotate_scripts:
  - name: nginx-options
    path: /var/log/nginx/options.log
    options:
      - daily
      - weekly
      - size 25M
      - rotate 7
      - missingok
      - compress
      - delaycompress
      - copytruncate
```

Comment: That's for the suggestion.  That didn't work for me.  Looks like I have to install the logrotate ansible package.  Instead of doing that I just ended up grabbing the `/etc/logrotate.d/syslog` file added the line I needed and turned into a ansible j2 template.